# Need to break the 2nd line of the equation

Tags: equations, line-breaking

```
% preamble
\newcommand{\wa}{\mathbf{w}_a^H}
\newcommand{\ga}{\mathbf{g}_{a_k}}
\newcommand{\fa}{\mathbf{f}_{a_p}}
\newcommand{\fak}{\mathbf{\overline{f}}_{a_k}}
\newcommand{\fap}{\mathbf{\overline{f}}_{a_p}}
\newcommand{\betasum}{\sum_{p\epsilon\beta_k}^d}

% document
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
  P_i^k &=& \mathbb{E} \left\{\left| \ga^T\wa \left( \sqrt{P_{a_k}}
  \fak{\overline{s}_k} + \betasum\sqrt{P_{a_p}}(\fa s_p + \fap \overline{s}_p)
  \right) \right|^2 \right\}\\
  &=& \wa diag \{\ga\} \left( P_{a_k} (1 - |\rho_{a_k}|^2) \fak\fak^H +
  \betasum P_{a_p} (\fa\fa^H + (1 - |\rho_{a_p}|^2) \fap\fap^H) \right) diag
  \{\ga^*\} \wa\\
  &=& \wa\mathbf{Q}_{a_k}\mathbf{w}_a
\IEEEyesnumber\\
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! I made some edits to your code that make it more readable, but do not significantly change the output (e.g. replacing `d_{a}` with `d_a`, factoring out common sequences as macros).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\newcommand{\diag}{\operatorname{diag}}

    \begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 P_{i}^{k}
    & = \mathbb{E}\Biggl\{\Biggl|\mathbf{g}_{a_k}^T\mathbf{W}_a^H
        \Biggl(\sqrt{P_{a_k}}\overline{\mathbf{f}}_{a_k}\overline{s}_k+
            \sum_{p\epsilon\beta_{k}}^{d} \sqrt{P_{a_p}}\left(\mathbf{f}_{a_p}s_p+\overline{\mathbf{f}}_{a_p}
            \overline{s}_p\right)
        \Biggr)\Biggr|^2\Biggr\}\\
    & = \begin{multlined}[t]
    \mathbf{w}_a^H \diag\{\mathbf{g}_{a_k}\}
    \Biggl(
        P_{a_k}\left(1-\left|\rho_{a_{k}}\right|^2\right)
        \mathbf{\overline{f}}_{a_k}\mathbf{\overline{f}}_{a_k}^H +  \\
        \sum_{p\epsilon\beta _{k}}^dP_{a_p}
        \left(\mathbf{f}_{a_p}\mathbf{f}_{a_p}^H+\left(1-\left|\rho_{a_p}\right|^2 \right)
        \overline{\mathbf{f}}_{a_p}\overline{\mathbf{f}}_{a_p}^H \right)
    \Biggr)
    \diag\{\mathbf{g}_{a_k}^*\}\mathbf{w}_a
        \end{multlined}\\
    & = \mathbf{w}_{a}^H \mathbf{Q}_{a_k} \mathbf{w}_a
\end{align*}
    \end{document}
```

Instead `IEEE{IEEEeqnarray*}` I suggest to use `{align*}` from `amsmath` (which is caled by `mathtools`). The second equation line I broke with help of `multlined` environment from `mathtool` package. For my taste is better to use `\Bigg(` etc instead `\left(` ...- This change is necessary in the `multlined` environment since `\left ...` and `right ...` in different lines doesn't work. I also remove all unnecessary curly brackets at variable indices.

**Edit:** As said @ Bernard in his comment, `diag` is math operator, so it has to written as such. Since it is not part of standard `amsmath` set of function, I add definition of new command for it and correct MWE as well image.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I tried with the following one:

Comment: @Zarko: In my opinion, you should make `diag` a math operator.

Comment: @Bernard, yeas, I should. However, said frankly, I was so busy with  cleaning the equation code and searching for parenthesis pairs that in the end I forgot on this. I will correct answer soon.

Comment: @Zarko: I know it may be time-consuming…

Comment: the "outermost" parentheses in the second line are not obviously matched.  they could usefully be one size larger.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, it seems that I were lost in forest of parentheses ... I correct equations.